# trouble loop in python

Tags: json, python-3.x, list, flask

I'm building a Python/Flask app I can't seem to loop over the return data 
request.form give me a ImmutableMultiDict so I covert it to a list which gives me the data I'm looking for but I can't loop it for whatever reason.

```
['[{"Service":"MED","Speciality":"PUL","docFirst":"HOPE","docLast":"CRANSTON-D?AMATO","docNum":"00970","docType":"P","id":3120}]']
```

Below is some of my function

```
def api_doctors():
    empty_list = {}
    records = list(request.form) # retuns my post data good 

    print(records)
    for i in records:
        for dude in i:
            print(dude)
```

When I print dude I get all the characters  in a line straight down.

```
[
{
"
S
e
r
v
i
c
e
"
:
"
M
E
D
"
,
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this line:

```
['[{"Service":"MED","Speciality":"PUL","docFirst":"HOPE","docLast":"CRANSTON-D?AMATO","docNum":"00970","docType":"P","id":3120}]']
```

Data inside yor list is just a single string, so that's why after iterating you have only symbols printed. Convert it to object using `json` module before iterating:

```
import json
records = json.loads(records[0])
for i in records:
    for dude in i:
        print(dude)
```

Output:

```
Service
Speciality
docFirst
docLast
docNum
docType
id
```